# How do I know when my carbon steel is seasoned?

Tags: seasoning-pans, carbon-steel

I purchased a Matfer Bourgeat carbon steel frying pan, and it's the first time I've had to deal with seasoning. I tried following their vague instructions, which were something like:

1. Clean the pan
2. Saute vegetable oil, salt, and potato skins for 15 mins
3. Clean and repeat step 2

But the pan didn't even change in appearance. After some online investigation, I tried scrubbing the heck out of the pan in warm water with some mild detergent. That certainly seemed to cause the protective coating to come free.

I then did a simpler seasoning:

1. Heat the pan
2. Wipe with grape seed oil
3. Wait until it smokes before turning off the heat
4. Try to remove excess
5. Let it cool
6. Wipe with a little more oil

There was a bronzing of the pan this time, which was encouraging. However, when I tried removing the excess, my paper towel sticks because the pan still has roughness to it.

I'm concerned that trying to cook in it will simply stick and make a mess unless I've seasoned "properly", but have no idea how to tell if it is actually seasoned properly.

How can I know the pan is ready to use? Can anyone give any advice?

Comment: There are reams of questions on here about seasoning. Start with the links automatically generated on the right of this page ->